# IShellItemImageFactory Icon\Thumbnails different from Windows 7 Desktop

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-api-code-pack

I am using IShellItemImageFactory to get icons and thumbnails for files and directories.  In most cases this works great, but in some cases I get an image that is quite different from the one in explorer.exe.

Folders in explorer.exe show some of their contents represented as pieces of paper.  Whenever I request an image for a directory, I get an empty folder in my program.

Videos playable by Windows Media Player in explorer.exe show as a piece of filmstrip with a thumbnail as the cell.  When I request an image for such a video file I get just a thumbnail with no movie strip border.

I am sure there are other examples, but in general I just want to know if there is a way to request an image from the system that looks exactly like whatever is displayed on the desktop or in a folder in explorer.exe.  I want everything to look the same so my program isn't "sloppy."

Comment: OK, for folders the problem was the image size I was requesting.  Anything above 96x96 was returning a stock image, below that it is customized for the folder (as far as I can tell anyway, have not exhaustively tested it).  Still no solution for video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144118(v=VS.85).aspx#adornments

The adornments are the effects I am missing and it seems I would have to render them manually.

TiKu on MSDN explained this to me and deserves the credit.